# Sublime Text 2 text selection within tags

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, text-editor

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to select text between tags, such as:

```
<div>This is the text I want to Select</div>
```

I've done some searching on google, the st2 site and here, but can't find this shortcut. I know command + L will grab the entire line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

I think that's the correct keybinding in OSX. If not, look for the `expand_selection` command in the default keymap with the arguments `{"to": "tag"}`

For windows/nix: 
Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank You.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + a` for non-Mac users. Press it a second time to select the tags as well.

Comment: @JitendraVyas In the ST console, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` and press the keybinding. What comes up? Alternatively, you can look under the `Selection` menu entry for what the keybinding is on your system. If nothing is listed, or it still isn't working, it's possible a plugin may be using the same key binding. The above mentioned log_command step should help gain some insight if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It only works if you have a language specified e.g under view > syntax. If it's just showing as a plain text file it doesn't do anything.